# Conflicting types with function definitions C

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am having trouble in understanding why gcc cannot differentiate between the following functions:

```
void a(int* p);
void a(void);
int* a(int p); 

void a(int* p){}
void a(void){}
int* a(int p) {return (void*)0;}
```

During compilation  "error: conflicting types for ‘a’" and "note: previous declaration was here" errors are being returned.

Comment: Because C doesn't have function overloads.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to overload a function in C. This is a C++ feature. In C a function can have a single prototype.

Comment: I wonder if *any* programming question can be answered without making reference to C++...